# How to deploy Jboss7 on eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jboss7.x

My eclipse doesnt not show Jboss 7 under *File -> New -> Other -> server*
Instead shows only Jboss 5 , which I cannot use to deploy my project since the error reads *The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification.*

Comment: Installing the JNoss Tools plugin solved this for me, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the "Development" version of JBoss tools, which includes the latest Jboss AS Adapter for JBoss 7, by pasting this URL into

Eclipse --> Help menu --> install new software:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/